# Multiple rich text editor in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I am new to reactjs.

I am using CKEditor Text Editor on my website. I want to add a function where users can click on add button to add as much as Text Editor as they want. While trying with this code I was getting an error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

```
    const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{data: ""}]);
      const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            const list = [...inputList];
            list[index][name] = value;
            setInputList(list);
        };
   return (
    <div>
    return(
     {inputList.map((x, i) => {
       <CKEditor
          name="data"
          type="text"
          value={x.data}
          onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
          />
         }
        )
    </div>
    )
```

Comment: Thankyou for the feedback, here is where i value came from                                                                                                                
  {inputList.map((x, i) => {                                                                                      
     <CKEditor
      name="data"
      type="text"
      value={x.data}
      onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
      />                                                                                                                                   }

Comment: Is that the exact code you have? That wouldn't render anything. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I have updated the code please once go through it. Thank you